# Meteor - how can I examine a particular Template's data context from the browser JavaScript console?

Tags: meteor

I'm having difficulty figuring out why a certain value isn't appearing in my template's data context.  How can I examine it from the console?

Comment: `Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {console.log(this);};`?

Comment: You can also use `window.foo = myobject;` and it will be available as `foo` in the console.

Comment: Or you could use [`Blaze.getData`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getdata) by passing it a DOM element (not a jQuery element) that's in your template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by @richsilv's comment I created a bookmarklet that makes this task quite easy. Once you've added the bookmarklet to your bookmarks, you can click it on any meteor page, then hover over the item whose data context you'd like to see, and click. The data context will then be printed to the console.

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to insert the bookmarklet as a link, so you'll have to copy and paste the snippet below into a bookmark URL.

`javascript:document.onmouseover=function(e){var evt=e||window.event;var elem=evt.target||evt.srcElement;elem.style.outline='2px solid gray';};document.onmouseout=function(e){var evt=e||window.event;var elem=evt.target||evt.srcElement;elem.style.outline='';};document.onclick=function(e){var evt=e||window.event;var elem=evt.target||evt.srcElement;var par=elem.parentNode;if(par.nodeName=='A'){par.onclick=function(e){e.returnValue=false;return false;};par.setAttribute('href','');};console.log(Blaze.getData(elem));if(evt.preventDefault)evt.preventDefault();evt.returnValue=false;document.onclick=null;document.onmouseover=null;};void 0;`

Comment: Thanks.  In Chrome I had to use the Bookmark Manager to build this bookmark correctly.